# export a column to bibtex.bib with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to create a link or button with jquery inside my content type(for example in the welcome page of the content type) that export the content of a column of this content type to a .bib file(for example bibtex.bib) ? if it is possible how can I achieve this?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but what exactly is a bib file?

Comment: .bib is the format of bibtex file. they are used for citation in scintific papers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BibTeX     it is basically a text file with a content like this:

Comment: @Book{abramowitz+stegun,
 author    = "Milton {Abramowitz} and Irene A. {Stegun}",
 title     = "Handbook of Mathematical Functions with
              Formulas, Graphs, and Mathematical Tables",
 publisher = "Dover",
 year      =  1964,
 address   = "New York",
 edition   = "ninth Dover printing, tenth GPO printing"
}

Comment: thanks for the clarification. From what I can see, it's basically just a string. It should be trivial emitting such a string with javascript/jquery. You'd have to look into the JSOM, if you're not familiar with it http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/hh185006(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: thank for the response. In fact, I have already prepared the content of the file in a calculated column in shareoint. All I need is to copy the content of this column to a .bib file for download when the user click on this button.

Comment: You cannot reliably (meaning, fully cross-browser) generate a file download without some sort of server side code. If you are targeting modern browsers (with html5 supports), then you can try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751704/1152344